# What is the difference between "memory" and "storage" keyword

Tags: memory, storage, ethereum, blockchain, solidity

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.6.0;

contract ZombieFactory {

    uint dnaDigits = 16;
    uint dnaModulus = 10 ** dnaDigits;

    struct Zombie {
        string name;
        uint dna;
    }

    Zombie[] public zombies;

    function createZombie (string memory _name, uint _dna) public {
        // start here
    }

}
```

Here I am confused because as per this post https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/what-does-the-keyword-memory-do-exactly?newreg=743a8ddb20c449df924652051c14ef26

*"the local variables of struct are by-default in storage, but the function arguments are always in memory"*.
So does it mean that in this code when we pass string _name as a function argument, it will be assigned to memory or will it remain in the storage like all other state variables?

Comment: I am not 100% sure. But I think the string_name in struct is stored in storage, while it's duplicate value (or reference) is assigned to Memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the state variables are stored in `storage` permanently. It is like hard disk storage.

Memory is like RAM. When a contract finishes its code execution, the memory is cleared.

Sometimes after you declared a state variable, you want to modify it inside a function. For example you defined

```
 Zombie[] public zombies;

function createZombie (string memory _name, uint _dna) public {
        Zombie storage firstZombie=zombies[0]
        // mutate the name of the firstZombie
        firstZombie.name=_name
        // you have actually mutated state variable zonbies
    }
```

If you used `memory` keyword, you would be actually copying the value to the memory:

```
function createZombie (string memory _name, uint _dna) public {
            // firstZombie is copied to the memory
            // New memory is allocated.
            Zombie memory firstZombie=zombies[0]
            // mutate the name of the firstZombie
            firstZombie.name=_name
            return firstZombie
            // this did not mutate the state variable zombies
            // after returning allocated memory is cleared
        }
```

### In solidity, function parameter variables are stored in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Storage store data in blockchain and it remains immutable. Memory store temporary variables, that included in functions(in this case _name) and their lifetime limited while executing this function. So when we pass string _name as a function argument, it will be assigned to memory, while your variable in struct(name) will be assingned to storage.